# How to distinguish multiple keyboards as like game controllers?

Tags: node.js, winapi, electron, keyboard

I'd like to distinguish each keyboard as like game controller in order to typing into separated editor in one windows app.

If each keyboard is connected to laptop, and a windows application can detect it as one player.

I'm going to use electron framework with node.js, but if I need some different tech, I can change over to different one.

Comment: The [Raw Input API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) can identify and distinguish inputs from specific devices.

Comment: @RemyLebeau then don't we need to map raw level value to alphabet or Alt at all?

Comment: I'd like to use its own input, only one thing want is distinguishing between keyboard's device Id and split into different view

Comment: "*distinguishing between keyboard's device Id*" - AFAIK, the Raw Input API is the only API on Windows that can do that from user mode code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks Remy! It was helpful, hard for me though :(